# Why won't this graphql mutation work with https?

Tags: https, graphql

I have been trying to deploy a app with an apollo server and I need a ssl cert for my app, so I went through that process, but now my login mutation that worked when it was served over http, doesn't work with https.

```
async login(parent, { name, password }, { req, users }) {
        // checks the name of the login against the database
        const user = await users.findOne({ name })
        // if username or password don't match the database the client will recieve an error
        if (!user) {
            throw new Error('Wrong User Name')
        }
        const valid = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
        if (!valid) {
            throw new Error('Wrong Password')
        }
        // assigns user _id to the session.id
        user.id = user._id.toString()
        // starts the session
        req.session.userId = user.id

        return user
    }
```

I should be able to login, but the server just returns null.

Comment: What's the actual response you're seeing from the server? Is it `{ "data": null }` with no errors listed?

Comment: Yes, just null, and the session doesn't start.